# findall/3の中でのへ

Tags: prolog

SWI-Prolog に於いて、以下の質問の実行について、質問します。

```
?- length(L,2),findall(A,member(A,L),L2),L=[a,b].
L = [a, b],
L2 = [_G89263, _G89260].
```

ここで、最初に生成される length/2 の二つの変数は匿名変数ではないはずなのに、
findall/3 の中のmember/2の中のAとfindall/3の第一引数のAはリンクされずに
別の変数が生成されてしまうのは何故でしょう。SWI-Prolog以外の処理系でも同じ
結果を得ました。何らかの仕様の原典があるのでしょうか。

Comment: まぁ、findall は自由変数をバインドしませんので…。`bagof/3` か `setof/3` を使うと良いでしょう…って、「釈迦に説法」じゃあるまいし、アホらしくなってきましたよ、尾崎センセ。

Answer (score 0):

Prologは理想的な宣言言語では無いので、動作した順番が存在しています。
L2が実行された時点では、まだLの中はユニファイされていないので、この動作が正常な答えになります。